# Inject the same instance of a third class into the constructors of two dependantly related classes using ninject

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject

Say I have

```
public class A {

    public A(IFoo foo, B bar);
}
```

and

```
public class B {
    public B(IFoo foo)
}
```

How would I set up bindings so that a new instance of **IFoo** is created for every **A** but the same instance of **IFoo** is injected into **B** that is injected to the **A** the **B** is injected to?

Effectively I would want to achieve

```
var foo = new Foo();
var b = new B(foo);
var a = new A(foo, b);

var foo2 = new Foo();
var b2 = new B(foo2);
var a2 = new A(foo2, b2);
```

Ideally the above would happen magically if I call

```
var a = Kernel.Get<A>();

assert(a.Foo == a.B.Foo)
```

I would start like the below which will not achieve this. I can't figure out how to set the binding constraints. Perhaps it is not possible or even desirable to do this.

```
Kernel.Bind<A>.ToSelf();
Kernel.Bind<IFoo>.To<Foo>();
Kernel.Bind<B>.ToSelf();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, you would use the "scope" feature of ninject:
https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Object-Scopes

Specific to your problem, you can use NamedScope, which is available in the NamedScope extension: https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.namedscope:

```
private const string FooScopeName = "FooScope";

Kernel.Bind<IFoo>().To<Foo>()
      .DefinesNamedScope(FooScopeName);

Kernel.Bind<A>().ToSelf()
      .InNamedScope(FooScopeName);

Kernel.Bind<B>().ToSelf();
```

The effect of this is that all dependencies injected into an `IFoo` instance (and their dependencies and so on --> the whole object tree rooting in an `IFoo` instance) will get the same instance of `A`.

(Hint: Call scope might also be sufficient to address your problem, depending on how the object tree is built).